# Switch statement not working as expected when reading characters

Tags: c

This code should take every char and see if its 'A' or 'T'. Then if it takes an'A' it should ignore the next 'A'characters until it takes an 'T'. it kinda like matching the 'A' and 'T' like a dna chain.

In the `while` loop, I'm expecting that in every loop it will take an another (next one) char, but the `switch` satatement is working just once.

How can I repair this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a=0, t=0, i=0;           //definitions
    char c;     
    c = getchar();

    //only the first 25 characters will be processed.
    while (i < 25){      
        switch (c){
            case 'A': 
                a++; 
                break;
            case 'T': 
                t++;
                break;
        }           
        if (a > t+1){       
            c = c - 'A';
            a--;
        }
        if (t > a+1){   
            c = c - 'T';
            t--;
        } 
        i++;
    }
    putchar(c); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic and code does not match, at all.

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: You're getting the new character _only once_ before the beginning of the loop, so _only one character is processed_.

Comment: When asking other people for help, take the time to demonstrate courtesy by using reasonable, consistent code indentation and don't make the code scroll unnecessarily by adding blank lines all over the place.

Comment: i need the process every char. so how can i fix it?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? The occurrence number of `A` and `T`? Or a fixed chain?

Comment: if input is AAAAATT ,  output should be ATT, for example

Comment: It's really not clear what the algorithm is supposed to do. Do you need to count the A and T? Why? What if the input starts with a sequence of T?  What if there is garbage between the sequences of A and T?

Comment: Well my question including only a part of my project. I want to find the dna disease. Only the first 25 characters will be processed even if it is gabarge. But first output must contain only A and T. The main process is counting the inputs if they are A or T. Because at the and i need to compare the number of A and T. If there is no equality then its a disease and i need to print the surplus letter. There is one more thing: inputs can be random letters and numbers. So i need to make every letter uppercase. also Im so sorry that first question was not clear. I will try to better myself about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't corrected its alignment and all. Just the logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  
   int a=0,t=0,i=0;           //definitions
   char c;

   while (i<25){           //only the first 25 characters will be processed.
       c = getchar();      // Moved getchar() inside While
       switch (c){
         case 'A': a++; 
         break;
         case 'T': t++;
         break;
       }   
       if (a>t+1){
          c = c - 'A';
          a--;
       }
       if (t>a+1){
           c = c - 'T';
           t--;
       } 
       i++;
       putchar(c);  //Moved to inside while
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That entire switch can be replaced by `a += c == 'A'; t += c == 'T';`, by the way.

Comment: this is working perfectly but when input is AAAATT, output is A    TT. I can not understand that space after first character. Have any idea to remove that space?